# What happens when the response from the CompletableFuture is ignored?

Tags: java, completable-future

I am experimenting with [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) in making [async](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) API calls. I am trying to understand the implication of ignoring the response from a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). The JVM technically executes the async API call and returns the result.

But in case we have no [`CompletableFuture.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get()) call to retrieve the response, I assume that the response is never being accessed in the code. From an operational standpoint, is that something safe? Are there any specific caveats/safety checks which I should be aware of when I ignore the response from the `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: If you ignore `CompletableFuture`, it means you threw away the reference to it, right? So when the async task completed, to store the result, and then it too threw away its reference. So now the `CompletableFuture` is unreachable, and GC will eventually get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting the GC to clean it up, but I wanted to be sure that I am not missing something. Do I have set up additional terminate thread pool commands or anything which would ensure that threads are not stuck in processing some kind of info?

Comment: What thread? The async task is done, often a while before you get around to calling `get()`. The only problem is if the object `T` in the `CompletableFuture<T>` is a resource that needs to be closed. Since you never `get()` the object, you never close it, so now you're leaking resources. Hopefully the resource has a `finalizer` to do cleanup, but that may take a long time before it runs, if ever.

Comment: @Andreas: In my use case, its a POJO being returned from the CompletableFuture and I don't think that's a resource which requires any sort of close operation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tight relationship between the scheduled task and the `CompletableFuture`. Your task will be wrapped in a job which will do the following things

1. Check whether the `CompletableFuture` has not completed yet. If not, continue with
2. Execute the task
3. Try to complete the `CompletableFuture` with the result

This processing does not depend on invocations of `get()` or `join()` nor whether you chained any dependent actions. Further, once the evaluation of the task has started, it even doesn’t matter whether you call `cancel` or `complete` on the future, the evaluation will continue and only the final completion attempt of the last step will not do anything when the future has already been completed.

In other words, the logic of, e.g. `runAsync`, is similar to

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable r) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(
        (Runnable&CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask)() -> {
            if(!future.isDone()) try {
                r.run();
                future.complete(null);
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                future.completeExceptionally(t);
            }
        });
    return future;
}
```

The `CompletableFuture` instance is just an object. If you don’t keep a reference to it, the code attempting the completion will have one until the attempt was made.

Note that the default executor, the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, uses daemon threads. So when you submit tasks in the main thread without waiting for their completion and no non-daemon thread is left in the JVM, it will terminate without waiting for the completion at all. If these tasks perform actions visible to the outside world, e.g. writing to a file, you likely want to ensure their completion, so may invoke [`awaitQuiescence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to ensure that no background task is running before shutting down the JVM.